# Perfoming a conditional statement on a GROUPED data frame in pandas using jupyter notebook

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

I get the following error:

TypeError: ‘>=’ not supported between instances of ‘SeriesGroupBy’ and ‘int’

when I perform a conditional on a column of a GROUPED data frame.

```
       group_school_data["reading_score"] >=70
```

I do not have this problem when I use the same syntax on a regular data frame (non-grouped). So when I type:

```
       school_data_complete["reading_score"] >=70
```

I get a filtered list that performed a boolean and made all instances of 'reading score' >= 70 to 'True'.  Which I can sum up.

However, the 'group_school_data' is a grouped data frame performed on the 'school_data_complete' by grouping the dataframe by school name as follow:

```
     group_school_data = school_data_complete.groupby(["school_name"])
```

1. When I searched Stackoverflow, I did not find any hints. The most popular response shows how to create a grouped data frame based on an if condition, which is not what I am looking for.
2. I also watched the syntax that was suggested in the following instructional video for a non-grouped data frame, but I get the same error message. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wJhdZfuO2ZA

My code works for a regular data frame and returns a series.

```
       school_data_complete["reading_score"] >=70
```

But does not work for a grouped data frame

```
       group_school_data["reading_score"] >=70
```

and returns:

TypeError: ‘>=’ not supported between instances of ‘SeriesGroupBy’ and ‘int’

'group_school_data' is a grouped data frame performed on the 'school_data_complete' by grouping the dataframe by school as follow:

```
    group_school_data = school_data_complete.groupby(["school_name"])
```

and the grouping returned a data frame using .head()

I expect to get a list or series when I perform the same on a grouped data frame but I get

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 group_school_data["math_score"] >= 70

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'SeriesGroupBy' and 'int'

Comment: Please edit your post to enhance readability

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems like you want to create the Boolean column **before** your group, then group and sum that Boolean column? I.e. `(school_data_complete["reading_score"] >=70).groupby(school_data_complete.school_name).sum()`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried it, and looks like it worked!  I will follow up once I confirm

Comment: Hello RX9.  I confirmed it and it did work, so thank you again, however, I think the 2 parentheses at the beginning & end of your expression, make the returned list to a tuple because when I try to add this new list into a NEW data frame I get the following error:  

TypeError                                 Traceback
<ipython-input-85-c21f4bef762f> in <module>
----> 9         ['% Passing Math' , grouped_passing_math]
     10         ]
     11 schoolsummary
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple

Comment: Thanks ALollz.  Your solution did work, the output is indeed a filtered list (series).  however, I am unable to append this new list into a data frame that I am creating.  For some reason having a conditional before grouping, does something to the output list.  I can view it in Jupyter notebook, but when I try to add it to the list I get the error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple